# Am I correct for cross-validation or validation set in libSVM?

Tags: cross-validation, libsvm

I used libSVM in MATLAB to find whether there is some relationship between the features and label. **My steps are:**

- Divide the dataset in 60% for training, 20% for testing and 20% for validation.
- I used the 60% and 20%(validation) as the input of SVMTrain. And I added a '- v' parameter in options.
- I retained the 80% above with SVMTrain and the parameter I got from step2.
- I used the model from step3 to predict the remaining 20% and get the accuracy.
- Repeat the 4 steps above until all the 20%s are tested and you got 5 accuracies.

**My Questions are:**

- My comprehension of cross-validation is to avoid overfitting and find the best parameter for the best model on the whole dataset.
- Are my steps correct or not?
- What is the output of SVMtrain with the parameter '- v'?
- What is the difference between validation set and cross-validation?

Thanks a lot!